# I have two ListViews in a Windows Form and I want to make a selection from the first list view appear in the second list view

Tags: c#, winforms

So I'm designing a restaurant ordering system order page, and I want to make it so that the selections from list view 1 appear in list view 2 after they have been confirmed. The menu is on an SQL database, and the order will be added to a new order on the SQL database.

[image: Designer view]

[image: Designer view 2]

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Menu : Form
{
    //connection string 

    string connection = "Data Source=den1.mssql7.gear.host;Initial Catalog=dbchapeau202109;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=dbchapeau202109;Password=Mb8iX12_Bc?W";

    public Menu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonLunchMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonViewMenu.Visible = false;
        button2.Visible = true;

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection);

        sqlConnection.Open();

        SqlCommand selectLunchMenu = new SqlCommand("SELECT menu_item_id, menu_item_name, menu_item_stock, menu_item_price, menu_item_category FROM MenuItem", sqlConnection);

        SqlDataReader reader = selectLunchMenu.ExecuteReader();

        listView1.Items.Clear();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(reader.GetInt32(0).ToString());
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(1).ToString());
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader.GetInt32(2).ToString());
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader.GetInt32(3).ToString());
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(4).ToString());

            listView1.Items.Add(lv);
        }

        reader.Close();
        selectLunchMenu.Dispose();
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = "Add Selection To Order?";
        string caption = "Add Selection To Order?";
        MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
        DialogResult result;
        MessageBox.Show(this, message, caption, buttons);

        if (DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection);

            sqlConnection.Open();
        }
        
        else if (DialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are asking us to write the entire Button2_Click code.

Comment: sorry if it appears that way. what I am asking for is if there is a way to make a function to copy a selected item from one list view and make that selected item appear in the second list view?

Comment: See [How to copy the selected items from one listview to another on button click in c#net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2340439/719186)

Comment: that is what I was looking for, thank you so much @LarsTech!